# How to keep list state across recompositions using NavGraph in Android's Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What should I do to make my composable remember the list state when navigating back to it?

If I understood correctly, when navigating "down" the composable  is replaced by another one, so when going "up"/back it will create a new one and if I want something to persist in that situation I must hoist that value.

The thing is, I don't understand how to maintain a clean architecture if everything will be a property of my parent, in this case the activity which holds the NavHost and the `composables` for the NavGraph.

I've been looking to the Jetnews sample and they don't hoist anything to the NavGraph level, so how did they make the list to stay in the same position?

- Activity

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = NavigationScreens.Launcher.route
) {
    composable(NavigationScreens.Home.route) {
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<DealsViewModel>(backStackEntry = it)
        HomeScreen(viewModel) { game ->
            navController.putArgument(NavigationScreens.Pdp.Args.game, game)
            navController.navigate(NavigationScreens.Pdp.route)
        }
    }
}
```

- ViewModel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class DealsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchGameDealsUseCase: FetchGameDealsUseCase,
    private val dispatcherProvider: DispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(dispatcherProvider.io)

    val deals = fetchGameDealsUseCase().cachedIn(scope)
}
```

- HomeScreen

```kotlin
Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            SearchField()
            DealsScreen(
                deals = viewModel.deals,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 84.dp),
                onItemClick = onItemClick
            )
        }
    }
```

- DealsScreen

```kotlin
fun DealsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    deals: Flow<PagingData<Game>>,
    onItemClick: (Game) -> Unit,
) {
    val nColumns = 3
    val content = deals.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(nColumns),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .composed { modifier },
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
    ) {
        items(content) { game ->
            game?.let {
                DealsContent(game, onItemClick)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference I noted between my code and theirs is that they don't collect the data on the composable, but instead the use a producer which in this case I don't know what to do since I'm using the `collectAsLazyPagingItems`. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Full code is available at https://github.com/Danil0v3s/wishlisted-android/tree/compose

Edit: I've found that there's actually a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177245496) which makes the composable defaults the list to initial position when the `collectAsLazyPagingItems` is used inside a NavHost

Comment: Try to use `state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),` in your `LazyVerticalGrid()`

Comment: Hey, I've tried that as well. Happens that there's a bug which was fixed last week (5/26)... Need to wait until next release

Comment: @DaniloLemes Is this still broken? Do you have the bug reference? I'm not sure I'm encountering this same bug, but payment. Using `1.0.0-beta09` (I see your sample uses `beta08`.)

Comment: Hey, I don't think it still happens since beta09